# What is the best way to convert a list of user data into objects?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of users where each element represents another list of user data like so:

```
users = [
    ["name1", 24, "address1"],
    ["name2", 54, "address2"],
    ["name3", 32, "address3"]
]
```

For me to access the age of the first user I would have to do this:

```
print(users[0][1])
```

output:

```
24
```

But instead I want a way to turn each list element into a user object so its easier to access, for example:

```
print(user1.age)
```

output:

```
24
```

What is the best way to approach my situation? I essentially just want an easier way to access user data from a bunch of lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are seeking the `namedtuple` type in Python.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

```
from collections import namedtuple

User = namedtuple('User', ['name','age','address'] )

users = [
    # name # age # address
    ["name1", 24, "address1"],
    ["name2", 54, "address2"],
    ["name3", 32, "address3"]
]

users = [User(*k) for k in users]
print(users)
print(users[0].age)
```

Output:

```
[User(name='name1', age=24, address='address1'), User(name='name2', age=54, address='address2'), User(name='name3', age=32, address='address3')]
24
```

Comment: @SmooK Just to be sure: you don't want to be able to change the values? (e.g., `users[0].age += 1`)

Comment: @KellyBundy No, I essentially have a spreadsheet where each row represents a user and I just wanted an easier way to access their data instead of list indexing. I know that a database would be more suitable for this, but unfortunately I have to store the user data in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

`namedtuple` is perfect for this. If you ever need to do more complex things with the `User` object though, a `dataclass` could be the next step.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

users = [
    ["firstname1 name1", 24, "address1"],
    ["firstname2 name2", 54, "address2"],
    ["firstname3 name3", 32, "address3"]
]

@dataclass
class User:
    name: str
    age: int
    address: str

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self.name.split()[0]

user_objects = [User(*u) for u in users]
```

Now you can do:

```py
>>> user_objects[0].age
24
>>> user_objects[0].name
firstname1 name1
>>> user_objects[0].first_name
firstname1
```

Comment: I'll give that a try aswell. Are there any benefits to using this instead of a namedtuple?

Comment: The `namedtuple` has less typing, but the elements are read-only.  A `dataclass` takes more work to set up, but is more flexible.